# Add Prism Content Control in Silverlight Templated Control

Tags: silverlight, properties, module, controls, prism

I have a Silverlight Templated Control with a Content Property.

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ContentProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Content", typeof(FrameworkElement), typeof(MyControl), new PropertyMetadata(null));

public FrameworkElement Content
{
    get { return (FrameworkElement)GetValue(ContentProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ContentProperty, value); }
}
```

Generic.xaml

```
 <Border x:Name="bContent" CornerRadius="0,7,7,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1">
       <ContentPresenter x:Name="PART_Content" Grid.Row="1" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
 </Border>
```

Now when I add the Prism Module in the Templated Control i cant see the Content ? Whats wrong...?

```
<local:MyControl>
     <local:MyControl.Content>
          <ContentControl x:Name="myRegion" Regions:RegionManager.RegionName="myRegion" />
     </local:MyControl.Content>
</local:MyControl>
```

Comment: Your problem solved?

Answer (score 0):

You have not set any content into your `ContentControl`, the `ContentControl` itself does not have any visible stuff to show if you are not providing any content like ... "Hello World".